# Test api url with public/private key authentication in soapui

Tags: api, soapui

I am a rookie soapui user and am looking for help testing an api url.

The url is below, however it also requires authentication of a public and private key.

If anyone can give me pointers on how to test this in soapui, I would super greatly appreciate it.  I know I am missing something obvious.

url: https://api.e2ma.net/9999999/mailings

$public_api_key:$private_api_key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like its **Rest API**

you can load the **URL** and then in left corner in middle frame in below picture, click that option of **Auth** , a popup will open

select **Basic / OAuth** and mention the credentials, then you should be able to run the API.

For **Basic** you need to enter **username/password**

For **OAth 2.0**, you will need to enter **token**

This way credentials can be added to a request in **Soap UI** tool

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gaurav khurana!  Typical me, I over complicated it and basic authorization worked.  Next I need to figure out how to add a 'with_html_body' boolean parameter to the output.

Comment: Good to know it worked. Can you accept this as an answer. Why you want to manipulate the output ? whats the purpose.. may be you can post another question to clarify and comment here with link so i can get notified and have a look at it.

Comment: The api has optional parameters [http://api.myemma.com/api/external/mailings.html] that I need to access.
Specifically the with_html_body parameter from the GET /#account_id/mailings

Comment: these headers are for reuest , https://imgur.com/5iJtSQO  this image should hlep you how to add parameters for get request , let me know if it does not help

Comment: Thank you so much!  It worked.  Next step for me is to transfer this to php!